# select item in a listview

Tags: java, android

I have created a basic list for a menu in a little app im making but im struggling to create the method that will trigger the events when a user clicks on an item in the list.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    String[] values = new String[] {
      "Home", "Profile", "Messenger", "Discussion", "Browse Library", "Grades", "Help"
    };
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
      list.add(values[i]);
    }
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

for now its just displaying a Toast but I want it to start new activities or fragments

Comment: So are you failed to start activity or fragment?

Comment: what problem you are getting in starting new activity in same way as you are currently showing toast message on ListView items click?

Comment: i cant select anything in the list

Comment: @Rhyno_H : but in question you are saying Toast is displaying on ListView item click?

Comment: no thats just to see if it works...but its not doing anything

Comment: ok it displays now but only when i click on the word not the whole row of the entry...any ideas on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
          startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So what is your question?
To start an activity just use an Intent.

```
startActivty(new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourNewActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy :

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg1, View v, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, anotherActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);

        }
});
```